# AngularJS, ui-router not showing templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AnguarJS and to be honest a bit confused right now.
I just started getting into routing and create this very small app just for testing, but it's not working.
Let me share the entire app, which is... just 2 files:

1/ app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router'])

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: 'first',
        template: `<h1>First message</h1>`
    });
}]);
```

2/ index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ui routing testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <a href="#/first">First Message</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's it! But when I run the app with `npx http-server -o` the `template`doesn't show when I click and land on the `#/first` url.
Does anyone have an idea where the problem comes from?

Comment: Did you check console to see if there are any erros ?

Comment: I believe you have designed the template ina specific state named 'firstMessage'. So u have to navigate to that state explicitly

Comment: In your app.js , try $state.go('firstmessage'). That will make you navigate to that state. The router by default doesn't know which state to load

Comment: Thank you, you all deserve your replies to be accepted. There were several problems with my app and you all helped me solve them :)
No I hadn't check my console (wtf, it's always the first thing I do usually...)
Turns out that I forgot to assign my angular app declaration to the variable ```app``` that I am calling ```config``` on just after.
Also I forgot the ```/``` before ```first``` in my url... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `/` in your url property

```js
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router'])

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: '/first', // HERE
        template: `<h1>First message</h1>`
    });
}]);
```

Comment: OMG thank you! This was actually not the only problem but it was one or them. ```app.config``` was referring to nothing as I hadn't assigned my angular declaration to a 
```app``` variable. Or I should have applied the ```.config``` directly after the ´´´.module``` ... I don't know if that' very clear.
Anyway, thanks again!